# Set a float value to JSpinner with 2 decimals

Tags: java, swing, decimal, decimalformat, jspinner

I need to set a float value of a `JSpinner` with 2 decimals, but I always have this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal value
at java.desktop/javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel.setValue(SpinnerNumberModel.java:456)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JSpinner.setValue(JSpinner.java:355)
```

all Spinners has this model --> `SpinnerNumberModel(0.01, 0.01, 10000.00, 0.01);`

```
float a = Float.parseFloat(aSpinner.getValue().toString());
float b = Float.parseFloat(bSpinner.getValue().toString());
float c = b / 100 * 95;
DecimalFormat decimalformat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
cSpinner.setValue(decimalformat.format(c));
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to give it a float value and it doesn't work, I tried to give it a String value and it doesn't work.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: 1) generally you would use a Double not a Float, 2) search the site for examples the use a JSpinner and SpinnerNumberModel, to so what those examples do. And you would want to use a spinner editor. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Spinners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html#format) for more information.

Comment: `setValue` was given a String; that does not work, should be a Number or Date or such. Indeed as said look at examples.

Comment: Thanks guys, I solved using BigDecimal class. Now it works without any problems!

Answer (score 0):

[`NumberFormat.format(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format(double)) returns a `String`, where as `setValue` when the spinner has a `SpinnerNumberModel` will be expecting a *numeric* value (e.g. `float` or `double`).

On a wider note, number formats are only intended to be used for *output* on a GUI (the view) or printing to the console or a file, etc. Internally (in the model etc) the value should be numeric.